# Nested "SET" not working as expected in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm messing around with some batch files right now, and I'm experiencing some behavior using SET that I can't figure out.

I am parsing files generated by a command line utility in an attempt to verify register writes.

My test code is this:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=>=- " %%A in (test.log) do (
    if %%A == write (
        set WVAL= %%F
        set WVAL
        echo Write value is %WVAL% )
)
pause
```

(FYI, in the test.log file, there are two lines whose first parameter is "write").

The output of this batch file is this:

```
WVAL= 0x2100
Write value is
WVAL= 0x24c0
Write value is
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Clearly WVAL is being set (as indicated by the standalone "set WVAL" command".  But why isn't it displaying the value when i use it in the echo line?

To add to my confusion, if I arbitrarily set WVAL outside of the for loop, it works.  For example:

```
@echo off
set WVAL=2
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=>=- " %%A in (test.log) do (
    if %%A == write (
        set WVAL= %%F
        set WVAL
        echo Write value is %WVAL% )
)
pause
```

will return this:

```
WVAL= 0x2100
Write value is 2
WVAL= 0x24c0
Write value is 2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any idea why this is?

Thanks.

-Sean

Comment: This seems like a job for superman/[delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Delayed expansion is apparently exactly what is needed.  Found an identical question moments after I posted this one.

Answer (score 0):

Literally 5 seconds after posting, I found this thread which answers my question exactly:

[Batch File not setting variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078870/batch-file-not-setting-variable?rq=1)

As Dennis van Gils mentioned in a comment, delayed expansion is in fact needed.

Thanks to MC ND in the other thread for answering the question.

Looks like I need to do more research prior to asking!